# How to make a bar chart for time duration with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The question is quite simple but I don't really know how to do it nor how to format my data.

I just want to make a simple bar chart like this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

But instead of having A, B, C, etc on X Axis it'll be days (16/01/2017, 17/01/2017, etc.) and on Z Axis I want a time duration. Max will be 24 hours. I actually have json formatted data for each days with seconds as value.

```
[
  {
    "date": "2017-01-08",
    "uptime": 40320,
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-09",
    "uptime": 74460,
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-10",
    "uptime": 73500,
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-11",
    "uptime": 83640,
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-12",
    "uptime": 68520,
  }
]
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is formatted fine.  Just swap out the variable names in the linked example; `date` for `letter` and `uptime` for `frequency`.  Finally since your data is already in JSON, you can inline into the `<script>` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .bar {
    fill: steelblue;
  }
  
  .bar:hover {
    fill: brown;
  }
  
  .axis--x path {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 40
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var data = [{
    "date": "2017-01-08",
    "uptime": 40320,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-09",
    "uptime": 74460,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-10",
    "uptime": 73500,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-11",
    "uptime": 83640,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-12",
    "uptime": 68520,
  }]

  data.forEach(function(d){
    d.uptime = d.uptime / 3600;
  });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.uptime;
  })]);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.uptime);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.uptime);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank-you. Is there a way to have the Y-Axis scale as hours and not seconds ?

Comment: @ArnaudJanssens, Pre-process the data and just divide by 3600, see updated answer.

Comment: Many thanks Mark, I was going the wrong way trying to display actual Date object in Y-Axis.